# Reading and formatting text files into Python

Tags: python, dictionary, text, formatting

I am trying to read a text file into a dictionary using python. When I open the file, it reads as follows:

```
SS,City,State,Country,Pop,Age,Random    
('321', 'Houston', 'TX', 'US', '84549', '45', 2000)        
('654', 'Miami', 'FL', 'US', '99999', '55', -2001)    
('940', 'Dallas', 'TX', 'US', '3243', '30', 324113)
```

When I go to open my file into a dictionary I am getting added characters that I do not see in the text file. I have tied stripping and removing characters but can't seem to get anything to work. Here is what happens when I print my dictionary:

```
("('321'", " 'Houston'"," 'TX'"," 'US'"," '84549'"," '45'",' 2000)')    
("('654'"," 'Miami'"," 'FL'"," 'US'"," '99999'"," '55'"," -2001)')    
("('940'"," 'Dallas'"," 'TX'"," 'US'"," '3243'"," '30'"," 324113)')
```

Below is the code I have so far.

```
locations={}
with open ("locations.txt") as lct:
    z=lct.readline()
    for line in lct:
        line=line.strip().split(",")
        ss, city, state, cntry, pop, age, random = line
    if state == "TX":
        locations[ss] = Texas(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
    elif state == "FL":
        locations[ss] = Florida(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
```

I would like the lines to display as follows:
('321', 'Houston', 'TX', 'US', '84549', '45', '2000')

Any suggestions?

Comment: where are this Texas and Florida functions error lies in there implementation

Comment: I created subclasses for Texas and Florida but right now only have them created and have pass under them. Im simply trying to get the file to read in properly before I add code to my subclasses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file is just a bunch of text where space and inverted also considered
using a regex can help you

```
    import re
    text = "('321', 'Houston', 'TX', 'US', '84549', '45', 2000)"
    pattern = r"(\w+)"
    print(re.findall(pattern,text))

>["321', 'Houston', 'TX', 'US', '84549', '45", '2000']
```

so your code will look like

```
import re                                         #Added line
pattern = r"(\w+)"                                #Added line

locations={}
with open ("locations.txt") as lct:
    z=lct.readline()
    for line in lct:
        l = re.findall(pattern,line)              #changed line
        ss, city, state, cntry, pop, age, random = l
    if state == "TX":
        locations[ss] = Texas(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
    elif state == "FL":
        locations[ss] = Florida(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
```

Comment: Nice, I think this did it! I still dont have single quotes around the last random value though. Will that matter when I use the dictionary later on in my classes?

Comment: ok... so if you dont need the single qoutes just format  * int(random) * when calling the texas or florida function.that will convert it into integer value.

Comment: single quotes matter when you are performing any operation on that variable. and It doesn't matter as long as you are just displaying or storing the data

Answer (score 0):

You can just slice the incoming string.

```
locations={}
with open ("locations.txt") as lct:
    z=lct.readline()
    for line in lct:
        line=line.strip()[1:-1].split(",")
        ss, city, state, cntry, pop, age, random = line
    if state == "TX":
        locations[ss] = Texas(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
    elif state == "FL":
        locations[ss] = Florida(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
```

Comment: is there anything else I need to add on to your fix? When I do a print(line) before my if statement I still see all of the quotation marks. So it now looks like this:

["'321'", "Houston'", " 'TX'", " ''US'", " '84549'"," '45'", '2000')

Comment: For each entry do this: `[i.replace("'", '').strip() for i in temp]`. Also, please upvote the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the three string 1. ( 2. ) 3. ' with empty string your problem will be solved.

Please use the below code

```
locations={}
with open ("locations.txt") as lct:
z=lct.readline()
for line in lct:
    line.replace("(","")
    line.replace(")","")
    line.replace("'","")
    line=line.strip().split(",")
    ss, city, state, cntry, pop, age, random = line
if state == "TX":
    locations[ss] = Texas(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
elif state == "FL":
    locations[ss] = Florida(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
    line=line.strip().split(",")
    ss, city, state, cntry, pop, age, random = line
if state == "TX":
    locations[ss] = Texas(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
elif state == "FL":
    locations[ss] = Florida(ss,city,state,cntry,pop,age,random)
```

Comment: I will try this but want to ensure I am understanding your solution. I will have to use two if/elif statements to get the data to populate in the correct subclass?

Comment: yes correct, but you need replace only at start of for loop and no need to repeat it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the format of text meet Python syntax, use eval will be easy.

```
text = """('321', 'Houston', 'TX', 'US', '84549', '45', 2000)
('654', 'Miami', 'FL', 'US', '99999', '55', -2001)
('940', 'Dallas', 'TX', 'US', '3243', '30', 324113)"""

locations={}
func = {'TX':Texes, 'FL':Florida}
for line in text.split('\n'):
    args = eval(line)
    ss, state = args[0], args[2]
    if state in func:
        locations[ss] = func(*args)
```